# Is there a way after using the fluent api of Gremlin/Tinkerpop 3 to print the query in text instead of list of steps?

Tags: gremlin

Right now I know that if I print the Graph traversal it shows the steps in an array. I am curious if it is, somehow, possible to print the original Gremlin query as a string.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each Gremlin Language Variant, there is a `Translator.ScriptTranslator` implementation that takes Gremlin `Bytecode` and writes it to a string. For `gremlin-groovy`, you would use `GroovyTranslator` as follows:

```
gremlin> GroovyTranslator
==>class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.GroovyTranslator
gremlin> graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> bytecode = g.V().out('knows').in('created').getBytecode()
==>[[], [V(), out(knows), in(created)]]
gremlin> GroovyTranslator.of('g').translate(bytecode)
==>g.V().out("knows").in("created")
```

Comment: Hi Stephen! Why there isn't any ```getByteCode()``` on the traversal? Is it because it is an older version of Tinkerpop or this is an older feature of version 3? I am using 3.2.3 with Java

Comment: I saw that ```GraphTraversalSource``` is returning a ```GraphTraversal``` that doesn't have the ```getByteCode()``` while ```DefaultGraphTraversal``` has it..  is there a way to work with ```DefaultGraphTraversals``` in Java?

Comment: I casted To ```DefaultGraphTraversal``` like that:
```System.out.println("~~~"+org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.JavaTranslator.of(g).translate(((DefaultGraphTraversal)traversal).getBytecode()));``` and I still get Steps in the printout and not the actual Gremlin query.. What actually worked even for Java is: ```org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.GroovyTranslator.of(g.toString()).translate(((DefaultGraphTraversal)traversal).getBytecode())```

Comment: Just to clarify - `getByteCode()` is on `Traversal.Admin`, so it is a bit hidden. So if you don't have a `Traversal.Admin` instance, you have to do something like, `g.V().asAdmin().getByteCode()`.